# How to turn url into a function in dart flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to turn the URL into a function but there's an error. (ignore the formatting, I have extracted it out from my long writing code)

--My CustomElevatedButton function--

```
class CustomElevatedButton extends StatelessWidget {
 final Color colors;
 final String name;
 final String education;
 final String eventName;
 final String clickEvent;
 final String imageURl;
 final String errorMessage;
 final String information1;
 final String information2;
 final String information3;
 **final Uri mylink;**

 const CustomElevatedButton(
     {Key? key,
     required this.colors,
     required this.name,
     required this.education,
     required this.eventName,
     required this.clickEvent,
     required this.imageURl,
     required this.errorMessage,
     required this.information1,
     required this.information2,
     required this.information3,
     **required this.mylink**})
     : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return ElevatedButton(
     style: TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: colors,),
     child: Align(
       alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
       child: RichText(
         textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
         text: TextSpan(
           children: <TextSpan>[
             TextSpan(
               text: education,
               style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
             ),
             TextSpan(
               text: name,
               style:
                   const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
             ),
           ],
         ),
       ),
     ),
     onPressed: () {
       sendAnalyticsEvent(
           eventName: eventName,
           clickevent: clickEvent
           );
       showModalBottomSheet(
         isScrollControlled: true,
         context: context,
         shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
             borderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(
           top: Radius.circular(20),
         )),
         builder: (context) => Container(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
           child: Column(
             mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
             children: [
               Image.network(
                 imageURl,
                 loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) {
                   if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                   return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                 },
                 errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) =>
                      Text(errorMessage),
               ),
               ListTile(
                 title: Text(
                   information1,
                   textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                 ),
               ),
               ListTile(
                 title: Text(
                   information2,
                   textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                 ),
               ),
               Padding(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                 child: Container(
                   width: double.infinity,
                   child: CupertinoButton.filled(
                     child: Text(information3),
                     **onPressed: () => openBrowserTab()**,
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
       );
     },
   );
 }
}
```

--My openBrowserTab--

```
openBrowserTab() async {
  await FlutterWebBrowser.openWebPage(
      url:
          "https://stackoverflow.com",
      customTabsOptions: CustomTabsOptions(
        toolbarColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ));
}
```

--How I call CustomElevatedButton and display it as widget--

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
        title: Text("Diploma Programmes"),
      ),
      body: new SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CustomElevatedButton(
              clickEvent: 'User clicked dia',
              colors: Colors.grey.shade200,
              education: 'Diploma in Accounting | ',
              errorMessage: 'Some errors occurred!',
              eventName: 'DIA_taylors',
              imageURl: 'https://i.imgur.com/uaHTJgF.png',
              information1: '\nTaylor\u0027s Diploma in Accounting is the diploma of choice if you wish o pursue a career in accounting and obtain a globally recognised professional qualification. The Diploma in Accounting will give you a strong foundation in various accounting and related subjects. \n\nThe Diploma in Accounting aimes to produce entrepreneurs as well as para-accountants with the technical skills and the fundamental knowledge required in the current er, for an accounting career in the industry and commerce, both in the public and private sectors.\n',
              information2: '• April and August Intake \n• Scholarships available',
              information3: 'Interested? Get more info!',
              name: 'Taylor\u0027s',
              **mylink: 'https://stackoverflow,com',**
            ),
```

Can someone guide me on which part of my code is wrong? Is it supposed to be final string not final URI or final URI?

BOLD are the ones relevant to the function.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem:

You're passing the string value "link" to the `url` property of the `openWebPage` function.

## Solution:

You should instead be passing the string variable `link` which holds a reference to "https://stackoverflow.com" from its usage here:

```dart
CustomElevatedButton(
  link: 'https://stackoverflow.com',
),
```

Change this:

```dart
await FlutterWebBrowser.openWebPage(
      url: 'link',
      customTabsOptions: CustomTabsOptions(
        toolbarColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
));
```

to this:

```dart
await FlutterWebBrowser.openWebPage(
      url: link,
      customTabsOptions: CustomTabsOptions(
        toolbarColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
));
```

## Update:

You can pass the `link` variable into the `openBrowserTab` function by updating your code to this below:

*openBrowserTab:*

```dart
openBrowserTab(String link) async {
  await FlutterWebBrowser.openWebPage(
      URL: link,
      customTabsOptions: CustomTabsOptions(
        toolbarColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ));
}
```

*use `openBrowserTab` in your `CustomElevatedButton` like this:*

```dart
onPressed: () => openBrowserTab(mylink)
```

Comment: I have to add that url: link might also depend on how the Url datatype looks like.
So might be url: link.getUrl() or something like that, depending on how the Url stores the "url"

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I changed 'link' to link under openWebPage, but there's an error and it says undefined name link. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

Comment: You need to put the `openBrowserTab` method inside the `CustomElevatedButton` class so it has access the `link` property.

Comment: You mean put this

```openBrowserTab: url:"https://stackoverflow.com",```

 into ```CustomElevatedButton```, like this?

Comment: Yeah. Also, can you post the full code of `CustomElevatedButton` if this doesn't fix the problem for you?

Comment: Sure! I have edited my question to make it more specific, thank you for your time

Comment: Checkout the update to my answer @ZXERSTON